# Use Dom to find value of script variable

Tags: php, dom

Assume a DOM document that has been loaded with an HTML page source. Within that page source is a variable defined inside a `<script>`:

```
<!-- a bunch of html page source code -->
<script>
  // ... a bunch of code
  var foo = "Looking for Mr. Goodbar";
  // ... more code 
</script>
<!-- the rest of the page code -->
```

My code has created a new DOM object, and assigned the $html code from a page to that object

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// load html
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

How do I search the DOM object for the value of the 'foo' variable? I want this result:

```
Looking for Mr. Goodbar
```

This is what I tried

```
$foo_value = $xp->query("foo");
```

Thanks!

Comment: hi Rick thanks for coming up with this interesting question. According to my knowledge on DOM i also would come to the same approach like you ´$foo_value = $xp->query("foo");´ - i will go and do further tests later the week - hopefully we can solve the issues.